# How to select a single record based on the value of a field in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I have an A-board:

| cont | tramo | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 10 |
| 1 | t2 | 20 |
| 1 | tc | 30 |
| 2 | t1 | 20 |
| 2 | t2 | 10 |
| 2 | tc | 10 |
| 3 | t2 | 22 |
| 3 | tc | 33 |
| 4 | tc | 44 |

And I am trying is to create a query that selects rows with the following condition:
For each value of the column "cont", if the value of the column "tramo" is equal to T1 then that row will be taken; but if there is no value of the column "tramo" is equal to T1 then the row that has the value of the column "tramo" equal to TC will be taken. In conclusion I must have only a single value in the column "cont".
The resulting table I need would be as follows:

| cont | tramo | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 10 |
| 2 | t1 | 20 |
| 3 | tc | 22 |
| 4 | tc | 44 |

I have been trying to put a "where" statement but it is not the right thing to do as it does not do what I need. If anyone has any idea how to find this solution I would be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Is the dated sorted by TRAMO within the values of CONT?  Note that `'t1'` is less than `'tc'` in lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Why would you use SQL for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted by CONT and TRAMO then using FIRST.CONT should do the trick since `'t1'<'tc'`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by cont tramo;
  where tramo in ('t1' 'tc');
  if first.cont;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method using SQL is:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from t
    where tramo = 't1'
    union all
    select t.*
    from t
    where tramo = 'tc' and
          not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cont = t.cont and t2.tramo = 't1');
```

Another method is:

```
proc sql;
    select cont,
           coalesce(max(case when tramo = 't1' then tramo end), max(tramo)) as tramo,
           coalesce(max(case when tramo = 't1' then value end), max(value)) as value
    from t
    where tramo in ('t1', 'tc')
    group by cont;
```